# How to get content from dynamically loaded website using Scrapy?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

How can I scrape this website https://charliesmithrealty.net in the easiest way with Scrapy?
What I am trying to do is, sending text parameters to the input fields for filtered search. Then scrape the data. This a dynamically loaded website. I tried selenium to automate it but failed to execute properly. It breaks at the end moment. I searched for the JSON file in the network tab but nothing was found. I hardly faced this kind of website before. So I have no idea about this. Here is what I tried so far,

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from scrapy.selector.unified import Selector
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class RealSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'real'
    
    start_urls = ['https://charliesmithrealty.net']

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        
        # selecting Zip Code
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='location']").send_keys("80023")
        time.sleep(1)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@lookup_field='zip_code']").click()
        time.sleep(1)

        # clicking on Price field and choosing min & max value
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(.//*[@class='bfg-dropdown'])[1]").click()
        time.sleep(1)
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(.//*[contains(@class,'bfg-input-option-list bfg-option-list-min')])[2]/li[contains(text(),'$150K')]").click()
        time.sleep(1)
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(.//*[contains(@class,'bfg-input-option-list bfg-option-list-max')])[2]/li[contains(text(),'$600K')]").click()
        time.sleep(1)

        # selecting beds and baths
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='BedsDropdownMenuButton']/select/option[@value='4']").click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='BathsDropdownMenuButton']/select/option[@value='3']").click()
        
        # search
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='Submit Search']").click()
        time.sleep(3)

        # pagination
        while True:
            try:
                more_button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-page='next']")
                more_button.click()
                time.sleep(1)
            except:
                break

        self.driver.close()

        html = self.driver.page_source
        resp = Selector(text=html)

        for urls in resp.xpath("//div[@id='bfg-map-gallery']/mbb-galleryitem/div/a"):
            yield {
                'URL': urls.xpath("./@href")
            }
```

Comment: Hi Raisul Islam, click method with selenium-scrapy is tough to work meaning most of the time they didn't work perfect way. Use standalone python selenium. If so then I can try to help to solve your issue.

Comment: I always appreciate your response and help. Please I'm waiting for it. @Md.FazlulHoque

Comment: See the solution, Sorry for a bit late answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hrer is the complete solution using standalone selenium. To extract data from this  website the way you have presented here is very tough and only powerful original
selenium can handle it smothly because I also wanted to integrate selenium with BeautifulSoup but didn't work because the elements are loaded dynamically via JavaScript after page loaded.

**Script:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import pandas as pd
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)   

URL ='https://charliesmithrealty.net'
driver.get(URL)
#driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
time.sleep(5)


view_search_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="nav-menu d-none d-lg-block"]/ul/li[2]/a'))).click()
view_wigdet = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//*[@class="nav-menu d-none d-lg-block"]//ul)[2]/li[1]/a'))).click()
search_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[name="area_search"]'))).send_keys('80023')

price_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="bfg-dropdown"]/button'))).click()
min_price = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//*[@class="bfg-input-option-list bfg-option-list-min mx-2 d-block"]/li)[2]'))).click()
max_price = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//*[@class="bfg-input-option-list bfg-option-list-max bfg-hidden mx-2 d-block"]/li)[2]'))).click()


select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "__bedrooms_total_min"))))
# select by value
select.select_by_value("3")

select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "baths_total_min"))))
# select by value
select.select_by_value("2")

click_view_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="label"]'))).click()

data = []

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

for card in range(2):
    try:
        cards = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="gallery-margin  bfg-rule1_1a bfg-rule1_1b bfg-rule1_2 bfg-rule2_5a"]')))
        for card in cards:
            price = card.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@class="bfg-price-text1"]').text
            #print(price)
            bed = card.find_element(By.XPATH,'(.//*[@class="bfg-text bfg-text-center my-auto"])[1]').text
            bed = bed.replace(',', '').strip()
            #print(bed)
            bathe = card.find_element(By.XPATH,'(.//*[@class="bfg-text bfg-text-center my-auto"])[2]').text
            bathe = bathe.replace('\n,', '').strip()
            #print(bathe)
            data.append(
                {"price":price,
                'bed':bed,
                'bathe':bathe})  
   
        loadMoreButton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Show More')]")
        if loadMoreButton:
            loadMoreButton = loadMoreButton.click()
            time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        break
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
       price     bed    bathe
0   $198,809  3 Beds  2 Baths
1   $198,103  8 Beds  4 Baths
2   $197,082  4 Beds  3 Baths
3   $196,963  4 Beds  4 Baths
4   $196,662  3 Beds  2 Baths
..       ...     ...      ...
67  $172,849  3 Beds  2 Baths
68  $172,624  5 Beds  2 Baths
69  $172,066  5 Beds  5 Baths
70  $171,187  3 Beds  3 Baths
71  $170,501  4 Beds  3 Baths

[72 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score -1):

There is an ajax request behind any JS-based website. so I have figured out which call is behind this website.

this is the request which is used to rendered data so no need to use selenium so you can request this

https://www.mbb2.com/version3/searchform/search-criteria?callback=mbbQuery34104041599161038898_1674040603155&acid=OLrJDh&LoadedTrigger=false&mbbid=44400357-9411-4b52-840d-35ae072a0ba&lacid=&mbbdomain=charliesmithrealty.net&mbbagent=&mbbassistant=&referer_https=true&mbbsource=&results_url=%2F%2Fcharliesmithrealty.net%2Fresults.php&mls_id=demo&search_radius=.25&zip_code=80023&price_min=150000&bedrooms_total_min=2&price_max=300000&_=1674040603182

you will get response and process it

Comment: I already tried with this url. But failed. @Muhammad Usman

Comment: which error you are getting, can you share the problem you are facing with this url